# Как получить абсолютный путь до файла при вызове контекстного меню в виджете, отображающем древовидную файловую структуру?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, файловая-система

Есть виджет, где отображается  древовидная файловая структура.

Первая цель - при нажатии правой кнопкой мыши на файл, должно всплывать контекстное меню, где при выборе пункта "Get file path" обслуживающая функция (в моем случае, это "on_filepath") получала бы абсолютный путь до файла, на который происходило нажатие. Как это можно реализовать?

Вторая цель - как сделать так, чтобы контекстное меню всплывало, только при нажатии правой кнопкой именно на файл, а не по всему виджету?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QTreeView, QFileSystemModel, QVBoxLayout, QMenu, QAction)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir
import os

class MyTreeWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Direct tree')
        self.resize(300, 400)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
        self.tree = QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        self.tree.setRootIndex(self.model.index(os.getcwd()))
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.vbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, e):
        contextMenu = QMenu(self)
        self.filepath = QAction('Get file path')
        self.filepath.triggered.connect(self.on_filepath)
        contextMenu.addAction(self.filepath)
        contextMenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(e.pos()))

    def on_filepath(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyTreeWidget()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При клике на дерево, элемент станет активным, а значит можно будет у вью ([QTreeView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html)) запросить текущий индекс и зная индекс запросить у модели (`QFileSystemModel`) информацию [о пути](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#filePath):

```
def on_filepath(self):
    index = self.tree.currentIndex()
    file_path = self.model.filePath(index)
    print(file_path)
```

---

А чтобы показывать контекстное меню только над элементами то можно сделать так:

Укажите вью:

```
self.tree.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
self.tree.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self._on_context_menu_event)
```

И реализуйте метод:

```
def _on_context_menu_event(self, pos):
    # Если клик не попал на элемент
    if not self.tree.indexAt(pos).isValid():
        return

    contextMenu = QMenu(self)
    self.filepath = QAction('Get file path')
    self.filepath.triggered.connect(self.on_filepath)
    contextMenu.addAction(self.filepath)

    global_pos = self.tree.viewport().mapToGlobal(pos)
    contextMenu.exec_(global_pos)
```

Теперь при клике правой кнопке меню будет вызвано только для вью, а благодаря проверке с `indexAt` меню появится только над элементами.

---

**PS.**

Если не нравится вариант с `customContextMenuRequested`, то можно присесть с `contextMenuEvent` или сделать наследника `QTreeView` у него реализовать логику контекстного меню.

**PPS.**

Весь код:

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QTreeView, QFileSystemModel, QVBoxLayout, QMenu, QAction)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt


class MyTreeWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Direct tree')
        self.resize(300, 400)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
        self.tree = QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        self.tree.setRootIndex(self.model.index(os.getcwd()))
        self.tree.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.tree.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self._on_context_menu_event)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.vbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)

    def _on_context_menu_event(self, pos):
        # Если клик не попал на элемент
        if not self.tree.indexAt(pos).isValid():
            return

        contextMenu = QMenu(self)
        self.filepath = QAction('Get file path')
        self.filepath.triggered.connect(self.on_filepath)
        contextMenu.addAction(self.filepath)

        global_pos = self.tree.viewport().mapToGlobal(pos)
        contextMenu.exec_(global_pos)

    def on_filepath(self):
        index = self.tree.currentIndex()
        file_path = self.model.filePath(index)
        print(file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyTreeWidget()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QTreeView, QFileSystemModel, 
                             QVBoxLayout, QMenu, QAction, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir

class TreeView(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.setRootIndex(self.model.index(os.getcwd()))  

        self.pressed.connect(self.pathFile)      

    def pathFile(self, ind): 
        self.file_path = self.model.filePath(ind)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, e):
        contextMenu = QMenu(self)
        self.filepath = QAction('Get file path')
        self.filepath.triggered.connect(self.on_filepath)
        contextMenu.addAction(self.filepath)
        contextMenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(e.pos()))

    def on_filepath(self):
        print("def on_filepath: ", self.file_path)
        self.parent.lbl.setText(self.file_path)
        #pass        


class MyTreeWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Direct tree')
        self.resize(300, 400)

        self.tree = TreeView(self)
        self.lbl = QLabel()

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()        
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.tree)        
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.vbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyTreeWidget()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]